# How to edit file mp3/audio... from android with targetSdk 11

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to edit an audio file, but when I want to save it I get the error below.
It only crashed on android 11.
Is there a way to save the edited file on android 11? I tried many ways and still couldn't. If you add access to all files it won't be, but Google currently doesn't support this permission when you publish your app to play.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/ringtones/AtomicBellRingtone1.m4a: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.xxx.soundfile.SoundFile.WriteFile(SoundFile.java:627)
        at com.xxx.soundfile.SoundFile.WriteFile(SoundFile.java:501)
        at com.xxx.RingdroidEditActivity$15.run(RingdroidEditActivity.java:1316)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8367)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
        at com.xxx.soundfile.SoundFile.WriteFile(SoundFile.java:627) 
        at com.xxx.soundfile.SoundFile.WriteFile(SoundFile.java:501) 
        at com.xxx.RingdroidEditActivity$15.run(RingdroidEditActivity.java:1316)
```

Please help me!

here my code writes a file and saves it to storage:

```
// Write the encoded stream to the file, 4kB at a time.
        buffer = new byte[4096];
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(
                    MP4Header.getMP4Header(mSampleRate, numChannels, frame_sizes, bitrate));
            while (encoded_size - encodedBytes.position() > buffer.length) {
                encodedBytes.get(buffer);
                outputStream.write(buffer);
            }
            int remaining = encoded_size - encodedBytes.position();
            if (remaining > 0) {
                encodedBytes.get(buffer, 0, remaining);
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, remaining);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Ringdroid", "Failed to create the .m4a file.");
            Log.e("Ringdroid", getStackTrace(e));
        }
```

Comment: Well show your code and the stacktrace from the logcat. Further: listing code is like allways. Tell which pointer is null.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace with exception message from the logcat. AND tell which statement causes the exception. What is null exacttly? I think you have the null pointer exception in code you did not post.

Comment: You should change your getFiles() function to returning a boolean and use it differently like `if (!getFiles("/sdcard")) return;`